# How to keep track of when a vote is cast?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sort

I have setup a great voting system on my website, but since I want to sort the top rated posts by week, month and alltime...I now need to able able to keep track of when a vote has been cast. Could anybody help/nudge me in the right direction?

I followed this tutorial:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-post-rating-system-with-wordpress-and-jquery/

JQuery:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery(".post-like a").click(function(){  
        heart = jQuery(this);  
        // Retrieve post ID from data attribute  
        post_id = heart.data("post_id");  
        // Ajax call  
        jQuery.ajax({  
            type: "post",  
            url: ajax_var.url,  
            data: "action=post-like&nonce="+ajax_var.nonce+"&post_like=&post_id="+post_id,  
            success: function(count){  
                // If vote successful  
                if(count != "already")  
                {  
                    heart.addClass("voted");  
                    heart.siblings(".count").text(count);  
                }  
            }  
        });  
        return false;  
    })  
})
```

Hooks for functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post-like', 'post_like');  
add_action('wp_ajax_post-like', 'post_like');
```

Post like function:

```
    function post_like()  
{  
    // Check for nonce security  
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];  
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ajax-nonce' ) )  
        die ( 'Busted!');  
    if(isset($_POST['post_like']))  
    {  
        // Retrieve user IP address  
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];  
        // Get voters'IPs for the current post  
        $meta_IP = get_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP");  
        $voted_IP = $meta_IP[0];  
        if(!is_array($voted_IP))  
            $voted_IP = array();  
        // Get votes count for the current post  
        $meta_count = get_post_meta($post_id, "votes_count", true);  
        // Use has already voted ?  
        if(!hasAlreadyVoted($post_id))  
        {  
            $voted_IP[$ip] = time();  
            // Save IP and increase votes count  
            update_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP", $voted_IP);  
            update_post_meta($post_id, "votes_count", ++$meta_count);  
            // Display count (ie jQuery return value)  
            echo $meta_count;  
        }  
        else  
            echo "already";  
    }  
    exit;  
}
```

Already voted:

```
    function hasAlreadyVoted($post_id)  
{  
    global $timebeforerevote;  
    // Retrieve post votes IPs  
    $meta_IP = get_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP");  
    $voted_IP = $meta_IP[0];  
    if(!is_array($voted_IP))  
        $voted_IP = array();  
    // Retrieve current user IP  
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
    // If user has already voted  
    if(in_array($ip, array_keys($voted_IP)))  
    {  
        $time = $voted_IP[$ip];  
        $now = time();  
        // Compare between current time and vote time  
        if(round(($now - $time) / 60) > $timebeforerevote)  
            return false;  
        return true;  
    }  
    return false;  
}
```

Is this doable with the code I already have? Any help or advice would be awesome, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines of code both store the IP address and time of vote,

```
// $ip holds $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$voted_IP[$ip] = time();  
// Save IP and increase votes count  
update_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP", $voted_IP);
```

The time a vote is cast is already being stored for you in the `post_meta` table for the given post the person is voting on.

To retrieve the votes and corresponding times for a given post you can do this,

```
  $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('voted_IP', $post_id);
  foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
    echo "$key  => $value <br />"; 
  }
```

That would return a list in a similar format to,

```
192.166.342.8 => 1349260674
202.646.100.3 => 1349260674
^ IP numbers     ^ unix time stamps
```

Comment: Wow, that is amazing man...thanks a lot for posting that up for me. I was previously told that my code didn't allow this (I was trying to sort the posts by week/month/alltime). Can I edit my OP and show you what I had for sorting my posts? Or link it to my previous post? Again, thanks Userabuser

Comment: @FrankMorrison No problem. Well... it sure does track the time. As far as editing your OP, no. Since that is a different question it should be in a different thread UNLESS you modify the title of your question to also include the sorting component then that *should* be acceptable. **BUT** if you already have another **Question** started on WPSE for "sorting" then ignore all of the above and link directly to that question in this comment thread. As far as **this** question is concerned, if it satisfies your need please mark and accept it as correct to close out this question properly.

Comment: Sure, no problem, I'll close this thread and start another. The post I mentioned is actually on stackoverflow, so might be best to start from scratch over here. I had another go, but not getting anywhere. Do you think im close, or is there a lot to go? If your intrested, here is the other post for now, but I will start a new thread. Anyway, im rambling on here, just want to say thanks for the advice so far, at least I know it does indeed track the time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619484/sorting-posts-by-week-month-all-time